# Converting char array into string array in VB.NET

Tags: arrays, vb.net

I am trying to convert an array of characters into a string array (where each character becomes a string), as I need it to be a string array for some processing on the array later in the program. Here is the code I am using:

```
Dim inputexpression As String = UCase(txtInput.Text)
Dim arrinputexpressionchar() As Char = inputexpression.ToCharArray()
Dim arrinputexpression() As String

For i = 0 To arrinputexpressionchar.Length
    arrinputexpression(i) = Char.ToString(arrinputexpressionchar(i))
Next
```

However, this throws up a 'NullReferenceException was unhandled' (*Object reference was not set to an instance of an object*) error. Why does this code not work?

Comment: Does the error state on which line the error occurs?

Comment: You don't need `i += 1` in a `For` loop.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You have declared but not initialized the string array.

You could use LINQ:

```
Dim charsAsStringArray = inputexpression.
    Select(Function(c) c.ToString()).
    ToArray()
```

Here's the non-linq way:

```
Dim strArray(inputexpression.Length - 1) As String
For i = 0 To charArray.Length - 1
    strArray(i) = inputexpression(i).ToString()
Next
```

Comment: What's the need for the first line? inputexpression(index) should be sufficient?

Comment: What _first line_? The first code snippet has just one line and the second("non-Linq") has this first line: `Dim charArray = inputexpression.ToCharArray()`.

Comment: `Dim charArray = inputexpression.ToCharArray()` but also `Dim charsAsStringArray = inputexpression.ToCharArray().` Why do you use .ToCharArray if you could simply use inputexpression.Select() because the String is already treated as Array of Char then?

Comment: @igrimpe: good point, edited my answer. That was just a copy-paste issue. Thanks.